# how to give style to a chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I try to make something like in the image, but I don't know how to do it

before I start write the continent of the chapter 1 I want to add the box style and under the chapter I want to show the name of the chapter and under the name I want to show what I'll cover in this chapter (and this part I don't know how to get it from the table of content)

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what of this you *can* do, and what of this you can't? At this point, your question is very broad. Maybe start with *one* aspect of what you want to achieve (e.g. the table of contents at beginning of the chapter? The box that says "Chapitre 1"?

Comment: The problem that I want in every chapter to show something like that (has the name of the chapter and what I will cover in this chapter that's it)

Comment: And in the next page I will cover what in the chapter 1 : means all the title in the table of content is just for one chapter and I will repeat that with the other chapter  and sorry for my bad english

Comment: The chapter style is definded in [`fncychap` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/fncychap), and a particular table of contents for each chapter can be done with [`minitoc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/minitoc)

Comment: Thank you friend that means a lot to me

Comment: @Ignasi that should be an answer, not just a comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This chapter style can be found in [`fncychap`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fncychap) package, it's called `Lenny` style.

And a particular table of contents for every chapter can be obtained with [`minitoc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\minitoc
\section{One}
\section{Two}
\subsection{One}
\subsection{Two}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you friend one more time